# pandas dates to and from int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` below:

```
import pandas as pd
d_range = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2019-01-31')
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d_range, range(10000)], names=['date', 'id'])
d_idx = m_idx.get_level_values('date')
d_idx.shape
```

> (69710000,)

Is there any fast ways to convert it to an `numpy.ndarray` of `int` that ideally represents the number of days after `1969-12-31`? And how to convert that array of int back to `numpy.datetime64`?

**Update**:

Posted my real use case above, which is a 70 million row `DatetimeIndex`. [ansev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214156/5025510) answer works, but it takes quite a while to run. Is there any faster way?

```
%timeit (d_idx - pd.to_datetime('1969-12-31')).days.values
```

> 2.08 s ± 6.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html) 
after subtracting converting to datetime with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
(d_idx-pd.to_datetime('1969-12-31')).days.to_numpy()
```

**Output**

```
array([10958, 10959, 10960, 10961, 10962, 10963, 10964, 10965, 10966,
       10967, 10968, 10969, 10970, 10971, 10972, 10973, 10974, 10975,
       10976, 10977, 10978, 10979, 10980, 10981, 10982, 10983, 10984,
       10985, 10986, 10987, 10988])
```

---

Or:

```
(d_idx-pd.to_datetime('1969-12-31')).days.values
```

---

```
(d_idx-pd.to_datetime('1969-12-31'))

#TimedeltaIndex(['10958 days', '10959 days', '10960 days', '10961 days',
#                '10962 days', '10963 days', '10964 days', '10965 days',
#                '10966 days', '10967 days', '10968 days', '10969 days',
#                '10970 days', '10971 days', '10972 days', '10973 days',
#                '10974 days', '10975 days', '10976 days', '10977 days',
#                '10978 days', '10979 days', '10980 days', '10981 days',
#                '10982 days', '10983 days', '10984 days', '10985 days',
#                '10986 days', '10987 days', '10988 days'],
#               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: thanks! But is there any faster ways? updated my question.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is the best